# Mysql,add value to a column using commas

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In my database, we have a column called `deleteList` which holds comma separated values. How can I append values to an existing record in the database?

Comment: If you are using Hibernate, you would have to create multiple objects... could you share your current code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to *UPDATE* the second time if you want to concatenate the values.

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    deleteList = CONCAT(deleteList, ',', 'NEWVALUE')
WHERE  colName = val
```

where

- `NEWVALUE` is the value you want to add on the list
- `colName` is the key that identifies the row to be updated.